# Convert a Json response to Obj in JQuery (Symfony2)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, symfony

I have just started with AJAX and Json
am creating a call for a thread of comments on my page when it finish loading
my controller return an array of objects in Json format
'[{"usr":"gigi","usrpic":"4993",..},{obj1},{obj2}]'

my Controller.php :

```
    //.. controller code (preparing results into $results an array of obj)
    $json = json_encode($results);
    /*var_dump($json);
    die();*/ // Problem 1
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse();
    return $response->setData(['comments'=> $json ]);
```

my JS:

```
$("document").ready(function(){ 
$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:Routing.generate('get_comments',{id:$id} ),

        beforesend: function(){

        },
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#comid_1").before(data);
        /*var newList = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(newList);
          $("#comid_1").before(newList);*/ // this gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (in console)


        }
    });
```

this is a screenshot for the jquery console https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9rHr.jpg
first, is there a length limitation with Json ?!!
And how can I start looping my Json response in Jquery ?

Comment: From your console in the attached image, seems like you return html string (not a json object) from the server... Try to return the correct type from you controller.
There is no length limitation, but large data will affect browser performance to render it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonResponse` is doing `json` serialization for you so you should pass there array, not a json (which is a string):

```
return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse(['comments' => $results]);
```

So basically skip `json_encode` and it should work - right now your server's response is a string, not a json.
There is no limitation of json length, this is just your firebug (or other tool you are using) making string (because right now you get `string` not a `json`) shorter to display